# Java Decompiler API

Tags: java, decompiler

Is there an API for the java decompiler presented here: http://jd.benow.ca/.
it claims that it has a **JD-Core** component, however I couldn't find any material on how to use the api. I am already using the eclipse plugin **JD-GUI**, i wanted to know if there is an available API for it.

Comment: you want an api to implement it in your code or want a software that can decompile

Comment: JD is a program you run so you can call it with `Runtime.exec`

Comment: BTW I suggest using https://github.com/fesh0r/fernflower written in Java which is a newer decompiler used by IntelliJ it not only decompiles lambdas accurately, it uses debugging information to reconstruct original line numbers e.g. for debugging.

Comment: @kirti, I wanted to decompile a couple of jars in my code making use of the JD-core api (if there is one available)

Comment: See the README.md at https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui for instructions on how to use it.  There is a brief User Guide  several links to blog posts on how it works at http://mchr3k.github.io/jdeclipse-realign/.